# How can I fix this illegal start of expression?

Tags: java

I am learning to program in java and I am doing a function that ask for two integers and print them in descending order and print the media between both integers. But it's telling me there is a illegal start of expression, can you help me?

```
public class TestFicha1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ficha1 f=new Ficha1();

        Scanner le = new Scanner(System.in);

       int a,b;
       double media;
       System.out.print("Insira 2 inteiros:");
       a=le.nextInt();
       b=le.nextInt();
       media =(a*b)/2;
       System.out.print(+f.decrescente(a,b,media));
    }
}

public class Ficha1
{ 
    public String decrescente(int a,int b,double media){
        if (b>a) {
            return ( "the order is:" +a+ "," +b+ ",media is:" +media+);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is error ?

Comment: `System.out.print(+f.decrescente` that `+` shouldn't be there.

Comment: if i take it give me another error

Comment: There is also an extra `+` at the end here: `",media is:" +media+`. And your `decrescente` doesn't return anything if `b<=a`, which you should also fix.

Comment: Use a proper IDE and it will tell you all this error, and help you resolve it

Comment: that's it, it's fixed, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have trailing plus signs. Please use an appropriate IDE for Java programming and it will explain your compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first + from

```
System.out.print(+f.decrescente(a,b,media));
```

Remove the last + from

```
return ( "the order is:" +a+ "," +b+ ",media is:" +media+);
```

Comment: if i remove that + form System.out... i can't even compile because says that is expected a semicolon in the end but already have a semicolon there.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to print the between two integer. you need to append media value by using + operator

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ficha1 f = new Ficha1();

        Scanner le = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a, b;
        double media;
        System.out.print("Insira 2 inteiros:");
        a = le.nextInt();
        b = le.nextInt();
        media = (a * b) / 2;
        System.out.print(f.decrescente(a, b, media));
    }
}

class Ficha1 {

public String decrescente(int a,int b,double media){

    if (b>a) {
    return ( "the order is:" +a+ ",media is:" + media+ ", "+b);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```